# Angular call a function in a directive from a radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

In the view I have a list with radio buttons.

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lyr in lyrslist | reverse">
           <span> {{lyr.layername}}</span>
            <input type="radio"
                   ngChange="setvisibility('True')"
                   ng-model="lyrname"
                   ng-value="lyr.layername">
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="sublyr in lyr.sub | reverse"> 
                 <span>{{sublyr.layername}}</span>
                  <input type="radio"
                         ngChange="setvisibility('True')"
                         ng-model="lyrname"
                         ng-value="sublyr.layername">
               </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

In the directive I have this function:

```
scope.setvisibility = function(visibility) {   
    layer = scope.lyrname;
    console.log(layer +' '+visibility );
};
```

How do you call the function and pass the lyrname parameter and visibility value to it?

Comment: Maybe it's just a simple typo: ng-change="set..." instead of ngChange="set..."

Comment: Oops sorry. I wont tell how long I've been trying to get it to work and the problem was right in front of me. Thanks for pointing that out.